# Responsive website-3 pictures in mainHeader section, want to hide 2 in mobile site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

By using css {display:none;} to hide the last two pictures, Succeeded. However the 1st picture shows being re-sized and became very small. After the picture, there were empty spaces. I guess that even the other two pictures were hided, but they did take space, right? How to solve it? I want to show only the 1st picture which should be suitable for mobile screen size and not leave space for the other two pictures. The 1st picture 's CSS was like this:

.mainHeader img  {width:100%;}

Comment: when using `display:none` on elements, they do not take space. It would be very helpful if you could post code.

Comment: It's a lot. Is it possible to post zip file somewhere?

Comment: Can you be specific about the issue you're trying to fix? Also there is nothing we can do without example code, and ideally an example fiddle.

Comment: Tks solved! Request for cancel the question.